# How can I add validation to an Input field? Binding JSON model doesn't work

Tags: javascript, validation, error-handling, model, sapui5

I try to learn SAPUI5 with Samples frpm Demo kit Input - Checked. I get an error message: **oInput.getBinding is not a function**

I have a simple input field xml:

```
<Label text="Name" required="false" width="60%" visible="true"/>
<Input  id="nameInput" type="Text" enabled="true" visible="true" valueHelpOnly="false" required="true" width="60%" valueStateText="Name must not be empty." maxLength="0" value="{previewModel>/name}" change= "onChange"/>
```

and my controller:

```
    _validateInput: function(oInput) {
        var oView = this.getView().byId("nameInput");
        oView.setModel(this.getView().getModel("previewModel"));
        var oBinding = oInput.getBinding("value");
        var sValueState = "None";
        var bValidationError = false;

        try {
            oBinding.getType().validateValue(oInput.getValue());
        } catch (oException) {
            sValueState = "Error";
            bValidationError = true;
        }

        oInput.setValueState(sValueState);

        return bValidationError;
    },

    /**
     * Event handler for the continue button
     */
    onContinue : function () {
        // collect input controls
        var that = this;
        var oView = this.getView();
        var aInputs =oView.byId("nameInput");
        var bValidationError = false;

        // check that inputs are not empty
        // this does not happen during data binding as this is only triggered by changes
        jQuery.each(aInputs, function (i, oInput) {
            bValidationError = that._validateInput(oInput) || bValidationError;
        });

        // output result
        if (!bValidationError) {
            MessageToast.show("The input is validated. You could now continue to the next screen");
        } else {
            MessageBox.alert("A validation error has occured. Complete your input first");
        }
    },

    // onChange update valueState of input
    onChange: function(oEvent) {
        var oInput = oEvent.getSource();
        this._validateInput(oInput);
    },
```

Can someone explain to me how I can set the Model?

Answer (score 1):

Your model is fine and correctly binded.
The problem in your code is here, in the `onContinue` function

```
         jQuery.each(aInputs, function (i, oInput) {
             bValidationError = that._validateInput(oInput) || bValidationError;
         });
```

`aInput` is not an array, so your code is not iterating on an array element. 
To quickly fix this, you can put parentheses around the declaration like this:

```
        var aInputs = [
            oView.byId("nameInput")
        ];
```

Also, you could remove the first two lines of the `_validateInput` method since they are useless...

Answer (score 0):

Usually, we set the model once the view is loaded, not when the value is changed. For example, if you would like to set a **JSONModel** with the name "previewModel", you can do as mentioned below.

Note that onInit is called when the controller is initialized. If you bind the model properly as follows, then the oEvent.getSource().getBinding("value") will return the expected value.

```
onInit: function(){
                var oView = this.getView().byId("nameInput");
                oView.setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
                name : "HELLO"
                }), "previewModel");
            },


onChange: function(oEvent) {

                var oInput = oEvent.getSource();
                this._validateInput(oInput);
            },

...
```

Also, for validating the input text, you can do the following:

```
    _validateInput: function(oInput) {
        var oBinding = oInput.getBinding("value");
        var sValueState = "None";
        var sValueStateText = "";
        var bValidationError = false;
        if(oBinding.getValue().length === 0){
            sValueState = "Error";
            sValueStateText = "Custom Error"
        }


        oInput.setValueState(sValueState);
        if(sValueState === "Error"){
            oInput.setValueStateText(sValueStateText);
        }

        return bValidationError;
    },
```

Please note that the code above is not high quality and production ready as it's a quick response to this post :)

Comment: I already set the model in Component JSON:                                                                              var oPreviewModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({});
   this.setModel(oPreviewModel, "previewModel");                                                          I don't want to set in my controller a new JSONModel                                                                   and i don't want to set static value because the input must be filled from a user

Comment: I see, it wasn't clear in your question that the model is set elsewhere. In that case, you can set the initial value for the input on onInit function. something like: oView.getModel("previewModel").setProperty("/name", "")

Comment: Does this.getView().getModel("previewModel") return undefined?

Comment: Yes,I use console.log(this.getView().getModel("previewModel")). It is undefined

Comment: It's hard to point to the issue since I don't see the code. Do you mind sharing the app sample url so I can take a look?

Comment: how I can it share it only with? I don't want that all users see my code

Comment: I believe private messaging is not supported in stackoverflow!